# Switching the format of this output?

Tags: bash

I have this script written to print the distribution of words in one or more files:

```
cat "$@" | tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n' | 
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | 
uniq -c | sort -n
```

Which gives me an output such as:

```
1 the
4 orange
17 cat
```

However, I would like to change it so that the word is listed first (I'm assuming sort would be involved so its alphabetical) , not the number, like so:

```
cat 17
orange 4
the 1
```

Is there just a simple option I would need to switch this? Or is it something more complicated?

Answer (score 4):

Pipe the output to

```
awk '{print $2, $1}'
```

or you can use awk for the complete task:

```
{
    $0 = tolower($0)    # remove case distinctions
    # remove punctuation
    gsub(/[^[:alnum:]_[:blank:]]/, "", $0)
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        freq[$i]++
}

END {
    for (word in freq)
        printf "%s\t%d\n", word, freq[word]
}
```

usage:

```
awk -f wordfreq.awk input
```

Comment: Thank you! I added a " " between $2 and $1 to make a space, then piped the awk output into another sort to make it alphabetical, now works great.

Comment: +1, but need to sort the output of the larger awk program: `awk -f wordfreq.awk input | sort`

Comment: @glennjackman - praise from the master; you just made my day :-)